# i want to put columns into multi index in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

for example, dataframe is below

```
   A B
a  1 2 
b  3 4
```

I want to put column to index
the result i want is below

```
    value
a A   1
a B   2
b A   3
b B   4
```

how can i get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a dataframe [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), and then turn the variable column into an index column

```py
pd.melt(df, value_vars=['A','B'], var_name='', ignore_index=False).set_index('',append=True)
```

Comment: your resolution is perfect! thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. Note that the other answer is worthy too

Answer (score 1):

You can [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) it:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=["A", "B"], index=["a", "b"])
>>> df.stack()
a  A    1
   B    2
b  A    3
   B    4
```